# Can't find 5xx URI errors in the logs (App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine

I see 95% URI errors for a certain URI, and the absolute number grows every minute, but I still can't find the errors for this URI in the Logs tab.

Any idea how can I debug this problem?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what you do, what you're expecting, what could be failing, ...?

Comment: It's our API that's being accessed by client part of our application. We;ve noticed that we're not getting half of traffic we expect, but we're not sure where it's failing. I see the errors on the dashboard but I don't see errors in the logs. Where should I be looking?

Comment: What is the latency for pending requests? You could have much more requests you can serve, and they won't appear in the logs, as they don't reach the GAE instance. They're kept in the queue but expire before being picked by an instance. In that case, you should try to increase the number of instances or its capacity, and to see a drop in latency of pending requests.

Comment: Average latency is 2.5secs accroding to the dashboard. There are other much more frequent requests which are all served correctly and I get no errors indication in the dashboard for them. We also have enough daily budget. I don't think it's lack of instances issue.

Comment: Are you using the old App Engine log viewer, or the [new one](https://console.developers.google.com/)?  Using the new one you can filter by status, e.g. `status:500`

Comment: @tx802 thanks, that did the trick! The new log indeed shows everything as expected. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @tx802: even the old log viewer supports the status, but the new one is better since it try to fetch more past data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the log viewer in the [new developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) you can filter logs by status,

e.g. `status:503`

It seems more reliable than the old one (and a lot more flexible).