# Increasing amounts of 500 errors on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We're seeing increasing numbers of 500 errors from Google App Engine that don't get to the server. Since these errors are not showing up in our logs, is there any way to track those down?

Normally when we throw a 500, we even render our pretty 500 page. However, increasingly app engine is throwing a 500 error to our users and rendering a simple white page with black text. When this happens, the request doesn't show up in our logs so we have no way to see what's happening.

This has happened in the past, but it's happening more and more over the last week or so. The app engine status page says everything is fine.

This is while use the python 2.7 runtime and we're not seeing Deadline Exceeded errors or anything like that (which is what I'd normally blame this on)

Comment: I am not seeing this behavior.  Try going to your console and killing some or all of the instances, to start anew.

Comment: Thanks, but at this point all of our instances have been restarted. We did it by hand, but also, it's been happening for a long enough time that all of them have been restarted anyways.

Comment: If you suspect Deadline Exceeded errors, you may try moving to a faster instance_class in app.yaml.  You can move back and forth, to see if that is an issue.

Comment: Are you doing any API calls in your code or is it really your page throwing a 500?

Comment: Sounds similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910014/cant-find-5xx-uri-errors-in-the-logs-app-engine/25919950#25919950).